# How to generate XLS file (no XLSX file) in golang?

Tags: go, xlsx, xls

I want to generate `.xls` file using golang.

I've found some libraries that allows me to manipulate the `.xlsx` files (reading, writing) but it is not what I need. Also, I've found one library that allows to read `.xls` files (https://github.com/extrame/xls) but unfortunately it does not have functionality to create such files. So my question is - is there any library which can help me to create the `.xls` file? Or maybe creating such file is trivial and can be done without any external dependency?

The other thing is, maybe I do not understand properly the difference between `.xls` and `.xlsx`? When I search info about `.xls`, google in general gives answers connected with `.xlsx`. Also, when I created a file using library for `.xlsx` (https://github.com/qax-os/excelize) and I've saved it as a `.xls` file it looked like valid file. So maybe this is the valid solution (using `.xlsx` library and saving `.xls` files)?

Comment: So let's start by the main difference between the `.xls` and `.xlsx` files. Both XLS and XLSX are file formats for Microsoft spreadsheet. XLS is the default file format from Excel 97 to Excel 2003 while XLSX is the default file format for Excel 2007 and later. So the question is.. why do you need `.xls` isntead of `.xlsx`?

Comment: xls is the older binary format. xlsx is the new format base on (Open Office) XML format. IOW, xlsx is a zipped XML obeying some XML definition, while xls is the proprietary binary format. Saving as .xls does not mean it is exactly in binary format and might cause problems. I haven't yet checked what does that excelize do really (a quick glance it is dealing with XML format). In the past I remember I did something with Excel automation, I can check that, it was windows dependent however. But, my curiosity why do you need xls in the first place?

Comment: To answer your both questions - let's say that I thought about using `.xls` due to internal compatibility reasons. But if I understand you correctly, nowadays - always if it is possible - the go to solution should be using the `.xlsx` format instead of looking for working `.xls` solution, correct?